# how to use jstree to show content in right div when i click some file 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

the tree file is on the left , and the content div is on the right , how to show

some data on the right div ,

this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jsTree v.1.0 - full featured demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_docs/!style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    body, td, th, pre, code, select, option, input, textarea { font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size:10px; }
    .demo, .demo input, .jstree-dnd-helper, #vakata-contextmenu { font-size:10px; font-family:Verdana; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo1" style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">aaa</a>
            <!-- UL node only needed for children - omit if there are no children -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""> bbbb</a></li>
                <li><a href=""> cccc</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="content">www</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({ 
        "themes": {
        "theme": "default",
        "dots": true,
        "icons": true,
        "url": "themes/default/style.css"
      },

        "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data" ]
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like http://jsfiddle.net/HthRD/1/ - the specifics are going to vary based on WHAT you want to write to the other "pane".